# Does it make sense to Freeze a Geometry/Brush even if I only use it once?

Tags: wpf

Example:
If I create a Geometry inside a OnRender method and it is never used elsewhere like so:

```
protected override void OnRender(DrawingContext dc)
{
    base.OnRender(dc);
    var geometry = new RectangleGeometry(new Rect(0, 0, 100, 100));
    geometry.Freeze();
    dc.RenderGeometry(Brushes.Red, null, geometry);
}
```

Does the `Freeze()` call here still make any difference?

Answer (score 1):

It depends. `Freeze` will make your code faster, since WPF will not care about lot of stuff any more, as freezed object cannot be modified. So if your code uses some objects frequently and it's performance issue, then you should try freezing it. On the other hand - if code is not giving you any performance problems at all, then you probably shouldn't care about freezing it (you know, *premature optimization is root of all evil*).

You could also use `Freeze` when you want to make sure, that nothing should be able to modify your object. This way, you can guarantee, that values you've set before freeze will be the same all the time. But this is dependent on your requirements.

You should also check [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms750509.aspx) to get some basic idea over freezing objects and then it may become clearer when to freeze.